# Triangle object with CSS is above text

Tags: html, css

I have a triangle made with CSS for a dropdown menu.
HTML:

```
<span class="top-link link-bar-link">Affiliate Content 
    <span class="caret"></span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
    #top-links-bar{
    padding:30px;
    border:0px solid black;
    background: linear-gradient(gray, white);
}
    .caret{
     border-left:5px solid transparent;
     border-right:5px solid transparent;
     border-top:5px solid black;
     display:inline;


}
```

The triangle is showing up, but it's above the text instead of next to it, as I intended.
[image: The triangle is above the text.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.caret {
    ...
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /* or 'middle' */
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/goeLwv61/)**

Answer (score 1):

**[FIDDLE:](https://jsfiddle.net/mrs_snow/oe9eky7w/)**

Try this:

CSS:

```
#top-links-bar {
    padding:30px;
    border:0px solid black;
    background: linear-gradient(gray, white);
}
.top-link {
    position:relative;
}
.caret {
    border-left:5px solid transparent;
    border-right:5px solid transparent;
    border-top:5px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```